# How to install Android Support Library and google play services on android studio?

Tags: android, sdk

I am not able to find Android Support Library and google play services packages in sdk manager

[image: SDK Manager Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses neither of those. Android Studio uses the Android Support Repository and the Google Repository. You have both of those installed. There is nothing more that you need to do, from the standpoint of the SDK Manager, to be able to use the support libraries and the Play Services SDK.

Comment: I must add Android Support Library and google play services but can't find them
http://8pic.ir/images/tevypqez6ppdh8qd20y0.png

Comment: @user2779537: "I must add Android Support Library and google play services" -- why do you think this? As I wrote, Android Studio does not use these. Your question states that you are using Android Studio.

Comment: for importing a project i need add them

Comment: @user2779537: No, you do not. **You already have them**. Please read the documentation for [using the support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) and [using the Play Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project).

Comment: Ok thanks. 
Support Repository instead of Android Support Library
but how about google play services ???

Comment: @CommonsWare: what is instead of google play services? Google Repository ? So if i have Google Repository i have google play services and if i have Android Support Repository i have Support Library
right ?

Comment: @user2779537: Correct.